# texture won't show up on object

Tags: texturing

My texture won't show up on this specific object, it works on all other objects in the scene.

Anyone know this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks like there's a texture on the selected object, could you please be a bit more specific, and maybe pack your image and share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: probably you need to look at the UV map of your object.